# SAS Export Issue as it is giving additional double quote

Tags: sas

I am trying to export SAS data into CSV, sas dataset name is abc here and format is

LINE_NUMBER DESCRIPTION
524JG   24PC AMEFA VINTAGE CUTLERY SET "DUBARRY"

I am using following code.

```
filename exprt "C:/abc.csv" encoding="utf-8";

proc export data=abc
outfile=exprt
dbms=tab;
run;
```

output is

LINE_NUMBER DESCRIPTION
524JG "24PC AMEFA VINTAGE CUTLERY SET ""DUBARRY"""

so there is double quote available before and after the description here and additional doble quote is coming after & before DUBARRY word. I have no clue whats happening. Can some one help me to resolve this and make me understand what exatly happening here.

expected result:

LINE_NUMBER DESCRIPTION
524JG   24PC AMEFA VINTAGE CUTLERY SET "DUBARRY"

Comment: That's standard for CSV files (or delimited text files) when a delimiter or special character is embedded into the text. Are you sure you want to change that?

Comment: What are you using to read the file that does not understand why the quotes are there?

Comment: yes, I am sure. Just need to know how to do it.

Comment: `A (double) quote character in a field must be represented by two (double) quote characters.` That's the specification according to RFC 4180 Standard via wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use PROC EXPORT to create a delimited file.  You can write it with a simple DATA step.  If you want to create your example file then just do not use the `DSD` option on the `FILE` statement.  But note that depending on the data you are writing that you could create a file that cannot be properly parsed because of extra un-protected delimiters.  Also you will have trouble representing missing values.

Let's make a sample dataset we can use to test.

```
data have ;
  input id value cvalue $ name $20. ;
cards;
1 123 A Normal
2 345 B Embedded|delimiter
3 678 C Embedded "quotes"
4 .   D Missing value
5 901 . Missing cvalue
;
```

Essentially PROC EXPORT is writing the data using the DSD option. Like this:

```
data _null_;
  set have ;
  file 'myfile.txt' dsd dlm='09'x ;
  put (_all_) (+0);
run;
```

Which will yield a file like this (with pipes replacing the tabs so you can see them).

```
1|123|A|Normal
2|345|B|"Embedded|delimiter"
3|678|C|"Embedded ""quotes"""
4||D|Missing value
5|901||Missing cvalue
```

If you just remove `DSD` option then you get a file like this instead.

```
1|123|A|Normal
2|345|B|Embedded|delimiter
3|678|C|Embedded "quotes"
4|.|D|Missing value
5|901| |Missing cvalue
```

Notice how the second line looks like it has 5 values instead of 4, making it impossible to know how to split it into 4 values.  Also notice how the missing values have a minimum length of at least one character.

Another way would be to run a data step to convert the normal file that PROC EXPORT generates into the variant format that you want.  This might also give you a place to add escape characters to protect special characters if your target format requires them.

```
data _null_;
  infile normal dsd dlm='|' truncover ;
  file abnormal dlm='|';
  do i=1 to 4 ;
    if i>1 then put '|' @;
    input field :$32767. @;
    field = tranwrd(field,'\','\\');
    field = tranwrd(field,'|','\|');
    len = lengthn(field);
    put field $varying32767. len @;
  end;
  put;
run;
```

You could even make this datastep smart enough to count the number of fields on the first row and use that to control the loop so that you wouldn't have to hard code it.